# Query making sum in the next child level of hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, hierarchical-data

I have two tables in my oracle db:
People:
IdPerson - PK
Surname
IdLeader

Earnings:
IdEarning - PK
IdPerson
EarningValue

There is a hierarchy: Each person has one leader, of course many people can have the same leader. The leader is one of the people in the table. Leader of some people can also have his leader and so on.. So thats the hierarchy.
I am trying to make a query that will return two columns:
- Person Id
- Sum of all earnings of people which leader is the leader with id in this row

Important thing is that i need only the sum of earnings of direct subordinates of this leader. So if any of people that have a leader also is leader of another group of people then i have to sum only the first level hierarchy.

For now i have a query that makes some sum, but the sums are wrong calculated, i don't know why

```
 SELECT LEVEL , People.IdPerson, SUM (EarningValue)
    FROM People JOIN Earnings
    ON
    Earnings.IdPerson=People.IdPerson
    START WITH IdLeader IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR People.IdPerson= IdLeader
    GROUP BY LEVEL, People.IdPerson;
```

What is wrong in this query? How it should look to make sums correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you don't need a hierarchical query.  Just do:

```
select p.idleader, sum(earningvalue) as earningvalue
from person p join
     earnings e
     on e.idperson = p.idperson
group by p.idleader;
```

Comment: Seems to work correctly. Thank you. I was trying with too complicated query for too simple result. But what if i will need also to sum earnings of all the next child levels persons in the hierarchy? So for the highest level it will be the sum of all next levels

Comment: @user2838197 . . . That would be a different question, and it should be asked as a question and not as a comment.  I would also recommend that you include sample data, desired results, and even a SQL Fiddle in a new question.

Comment: Here i created the sql fiddle for this question. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15e85/3 I also checked all the results calculating manually and you query is working good i think.